# Getting soulutf8 to work with luatex

Tags: luatex, unicode, soul

Is it possible to get soul(utf8) to work with luatex?  In the following
example only the first three lines are typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\setmainfont{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

foo
\so{foo}
ζῴῳ
\so{ζῴῳ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use soul with luatex, use lua-ul.

Comment: sorry just realized that \so is letterspacing, this can be done with font features or with microtype.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need soul with luatex, underlining and similar can be done with `lua-ul`, letterspacing with font features or with microtype:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,microtype}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}

\setmainfont{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

foo
\ul{foo} \textls{foo}
ζῴῳ
\ul{ζῴῳ} \textls{ζῴῳ}

\end{document}
```

[image]