lua-ul underlines with unwanted gaps
I'd like to stretch a word using the command \textls from the microtype package and underline it using the package lua-ul.
Unfortunately I get an interupted line:

See the gap in the line under the letters v and e.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}

\setmainfont{Garamond Libre Regular}[BoldFont=Garamond Libre Bold]

\begin{document}

\Huge\bfseries

\ul{\textls[50]{Gestattungsvertrag}}

\bigskip

\textls[50]{\ul{Gestattungsvertrag}}

\end{document}

I've seen this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586053/4736
Obviously, it would be great to underline stretched words without gaps in the line. Any ideas welcome! I tested with different fonts, so the gap does not depend on the font.

I think that I have encountered this exact same bug in the past, but with highlighting text instead of underlining text.

Edit
The bug is fixed in the development version of luaotfload, now font kern nodes remain with the same subtype when letter spacing is used.
Original
The problem is not really related to microtype, you can produce the problem with the following:
\documentclass{article}
\font\foo="name:GaramondLibreRegular:letterspace=50;"
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\begin{document}
\foo
\underLine{Gestattungsvertrag}
\end{document}

The problem is that the kern nodes inserted by luaotfload in the pre_linebreak_filter (at least in this case) does not have the attribute that is set by the \ul command.
Usually this is fine, as lua-ul is aware of that and tests if a node is a kern node of subtype 0 (font). https://github.com/zauguin/luaul/blob/bdfe9ed5036d51d27266252dc14473ae7d0e82fc/lua-ul.dtx#L745-L756.
When the letter spacing feature is used, then luaotfload replaces kern nodes of subtype 0 with kern nodes of subtype 1 (userkern). https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/blob/72561365e3de47c138418af7d11ab335683ff7f0/src/luaotfload-letterspace.lua#L340-L360.
I can't think of an easy and elegant way to solve it other than patching lua-ul or luaotfload. For example, changing the line
elseif id == kern_t and subtype == 0 then 

to
elseif id == kern_t and (subtype == 0 or subtype == 1)  then

in lua-ul.lua works. If you are going to modify the package in your local environment, remember to do that under the restrictions of The LaTeX project public license (LPPL), version 1.3c

Works! Thank you. How on earth do you know such a thing? I know you maintain some packages regarding hebrew, but this really seems a hidden bug. Should I open a bug report? And besides this, if I modify lua-ul.lua locally on my harddisk, which sentence of LPPL urges me to do something else with regard to this local change?

@KeksDose Marcel said make a bug report to luaotfload

@UlrikeFischer See https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/280 I hope I can remember that I changed lua-ul.lua...

@KeksDose I am familiar a bit with lua-ul's code, and I knew specifically about the problem with font kern nodes added by luaotfload because I encountered that when I was reading this article recently. Then by inquiring the list of nodes I've noticed the problem only occurs at font kerns, and that they are replaced eventually by user kerns.

@KeksDose as for the LPPL thing, I'm not sure, I just remembered people commenting about this in the past, but the post was deleted. Maybe it is to avoid from different versions of a file that goes by the same name being distributed (mistakes happen).

@UdiFogiel LPPL: I'm relieved, because I thought I had gotten it wrong. OK, the LPPL becomes relevant if I decided to publish an adapted lua-ul.lua version. Being a lawyer in Germany, I'm quite convinced about this point after rereading the lincence.

@KeksDose read the section under "A Recommendation on Modification Without Distribution", it is only a recommendation though.
